# how to compile mariadb with libmysqlclient.so? (missing libmysqlclient.so in /usr/local/mysql/lib)

Tags: php, mariadb

I just started to change our database from mysql (community version) to mariadb with the further use of php7.1/apache2.4.25...
So I have to compile mariadb in our new production environment.
I compiled it with these options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="-std=c++11" -DCONC_WITH_CURL=ON -DCONC_WITH_EXTERNAL_ZLIB=ON -DDISABLE_SHARED=OFF -DCONC_WITH_MYSQLCOMPAT:BOOL=ON -DPLUGIN_CLIENT_ED25519:STRING=DYNAMIC .
make all && make install
```

The mysql community version has a libmysqlclient.so in /usr/local/mysql/lib located.
If I compile it with the options given above I just found this files in /usr/local/mysql/lib (MariaDB 10.2.6):

```
    # ls -l /usr/local/mysql/lib/
total 3572
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2305518 Jul  4 08:14 libmariadbclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 08:31 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1297664 Jul  4 08:14 libmariadb.so.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48406 Jul  4 08:14 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  4 08:31 plugin
```

What can I do? Are there any other options I missed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I found a solution.
I've just did a symbolic link to libmariadb.so and it now looks like the following:

```
ls -l /usr/local/mysql/lib/
total 3572
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2305518 Jul  4 16:21 libmariadbclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:39 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1297664 Jul  4 16:21 libmariadb.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:40 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmariadb.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:40 libmysqlclient.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48406 Jul  4 16:21 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  4 16:39 plugin
```

In this case PHP 7 would finally find the mysql libraries...